# client side routing in meteor with iron-router

Tags: ember.js, meteor, iron-router

Is there a way to have meteor do client side routing in the way that Ember works?  I'm using iron-router, but it seems like the default behavior is to use the server to route the url whereas in Ember it does everything in the dom...

Comment: No, Iron Router doesn't work on the server only - you can put your routes on the client side and they will work. In fact, my personal opinion is that that's what you *should* do, as IR doesn't perform well on the server side anyway.

Comment: OK, so I moved my router.js into the client directory.  The browser seems to be showing as if its loading when I change routes.  In Ember, I don't see that because it uses the #! urls.  Is there a way to have IR use #!?

Answer (score 1):

Put things like followings into your client directory:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('home', {path: '/'});
  this.route('about');
});
```

Then you'll get a client side routing